# How to create a marklogic most basic 3-node-cluster from dockerhub marklogic images via gradle

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, marklogic

I am looking for any sample project to create **MarkLogic 3 Nodes Cluster** directly from ML **Docker Hub** image (https://hub.docker.com/_/marklogic) via **Gradle** on a single machine.

The idea is to auto spin off different ML versions for the dev enviroment set up.

Current [three node cluster example](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/docker-projects/three-node-cluster-with-ha-proxy) in gitbub ml-gradle is to install ML from rpm installation package.
I would like to directly use the [ML docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/marklogic) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) includes instructions for spinning up a cluster with this simple command:

```
docker-compose -f cluster.yml up -d --scale dnode=2
```

To run this, pull down the Docker image (you'll need an account on Docker Hub (free) and you'll need to do the checkout process to get access to the MarkLogic image (also free)). Then you can create the `cluster.yml` file using the example given on the setup instructions page on Docker Hub.

As @rjrudin points out, you can set up a gradle task to do this.

Answer (score 1):

ml-gradle is typically used to deploy an application to an existing ML cluster. To actually create the ML cluster, you use the "docker" executable. You can automate this via Gradle's Exec task if you wish, but doing so is outside the scope of ml-gradle which assumes that you already have an ML cluster setup.